# Unable to communicate to device with .local domain using android, corova-zeroconf-plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, iot, zeroconf

I am having an iot device which is advertising in my network with name iotdevice.local, i am able to send http requests to this domain in my windows pc after installing Bonjour. But i am developing an ionic app from which i'll be communicating frequently with this device. 
So i am using cordova-zeroconf-plugin. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-zeroconf). 
I am seeing the services when i add watch for .local services. but my requestis faield when i use iotdevice.local in $http function. 
I have this code
**App.js**

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
  console.log("device ready");
  var zeroconf = cordova.plugins.zeroconf;
  zeroconf.watch('_http._tcp.local.', function(result) {
    var action = result.action;
    var service = result.service;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    if (action == 'added') {
        console.log('service added', service);
    } else {
        console.log('service removed', service);
    }
  });


}
```

It works fine and in logs i see my device

> {"action":"added","service":{"application":"http","domain":"local","port":80,"name":"iotdevice","server":"iotdevice.local.","description":"\00","protocol":"tcp","qualifiedname":"iotdevice._http._tcp.local.","type":"_http._tcp.local.","txtRecord":{},"addresses":["192.168.0.4"],"urls":["http://192.168.0.4:80"]}}

But when i use this in **controller.js**-

```
$scope.sendRequest2 = function(){
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://iotdevice.local/events?id=600194067eba&action=socket1off'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.req2succes=true;
        console.log("Sent");
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log("Could not Sent");
        $scope.req2succes=false;
      });
  }
```

It Doesn't work. Request status is always -1. 
can anyone help me how i can deal with his. Am i doing something fundamentally wrong ?

Comment: Try replacing if (action == 'added')  with if (action == 'resolved'). That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use IP address instead of `http://iotdevice.local.`.Use `http://192.168.0.4:80`.Hope this works.

Comment: Noh, The problem is that i can't use IP, because i don't always know the IP, it's dynamic and may change when router's state changes. thats the reason i am having a fixed .local domain, which should always work even if IP changes.

Comment: In `zeroconf.watch` you are getting the dynamic IP.You can use that dynamtic IP

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, I'll be using that only until i find a better solution, because this will involve keeping log of ips all the time for all the devices. and one more layer over the communication part. Thanks anyway.